# Handling Next Record nullable reference Controller Code to pass to viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have researched various nullable reference handling posts, but not finding anything helpful.  So what I am doing below to handle this null reference (it's a hack for now to stop the error page from displaying to users) is to essentially return the current id if a next record does not exist in my edit controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var myInClause = new string[] { "a", "c", "k" };
    var myQueryResults = await _context.MyClass.FindAsync(id);
    int?  NextIdObject = (from i in _context.MyClass
                        where myInClause.Contains(i.RowType) && (i.Id > myclass.Id) 
                        select new { i.Id }).DefaultIfEmpty().First().Id;
    if (!NextIdObject.Equals(0))
    {
        ViewBag.nextID = NextIdObject; 
    }
    else
    {  
        ViewBag.nextID = id;
    }

    if (myQueryResults == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(myQueryResults);
}
```

I would prefer to just redirect to the index page (if they hit this error, it means they are done working through a queue anyway, no next record would ever exist here).  Or maybe just keep the code as is and display a message on the button to indicate end of list.  Any thoughts here.  Note, using any +1 increment on the id does not work for me, as I don't need the user to see all id records, just the one's with a/c/k which is why I bring the myInclause variable in.  If there is a better way to use the SQL sytanx of "IN" for Linq queries, I am all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would prefer to just redirect to the index page (if they hit this
>   error, it means they are done working through a queue anyway, no next
>   record would ever exist here)

You could use try...catch block simply like

```
try
{
     var myInClause = new string[] { "a", "c", "k" };
     var myQueryResults = await _context.MyClass.FindAsync(id);
     int  NextIdObject = (from i in _context.MyClass
                    where myInClause.Contains(i.RowType) && (i.Id > myclass.Id) 
                    select new { i.Id }).DefaultIfEmpty().First().Id;
     ViewBag.nextID = NextIdObject; 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
     //or return View("Index");
}
return View(myQueryResults);
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution!